# When month picker value is changed my day picker value will change in number picker using xamarin C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is my code, I would like when month value is changed my day picker value will change. Day value is depends on month. Like, if month value is 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 then day value will 31 otherwise day value 30. If month is feb then day value will 28 and will depends on leap years.

I'm using XAMARIN with C#.

Thank you!

```
public class DayMonthYearPickerDialog : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment
{
    public event EventHandler<DateTime> OnDateTimeChanged;
    public event EventHandler<DateTime> OnClosed;

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public void Hide() => base.Dialog?.Hide();

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = Activity.LayoutInflater;
        var selectedDate = GetSelectedDate();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.Instance;

        View dialog = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.date_picker_dialog, null);
        NumberPicker monthPicker = (NumberPicker)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.picker_month);
        NumberPicker yearPicker = (NumberPicker)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.picker_year);
        NumberPicker dayPicker = (NumberPicker)dialog.FindViewById(Resource.Id.picker_day);

        monthPicker.MinValue = 1;
        monthPicker.MaxValue = 12;
        monthPicker.Value = cal.Get(CalendarField.Month) + 1;


        dayPicker.MinValue = 1;
        dayPicker.MaxValue = 31;
        dayPicker.Value = cal.Get(CalendarField.DayOfMonth);

        int year = cal.Get(CalendarField.Year);
        yearPicker.MinValue = 1900;
        yearPicker.MaxValue = year;
        yearPicker.Value = year;

        builder.SetView(dialog)
            .SetPositiveButton("Ok", (sender, e) =>
            {
                selectedDate = new DateTime(yearPicker.Value, monthPicker.Value, dayPicker.Value);

                OnDateTimeChanged?.Invoke(dialog, selectedDate);
            })
            .SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sender, e) =>
            {
                Dialog.Cancel();
                OnClosed?.Invoke(dialog, selectedDate);
            }); return builder.Create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a ValueChanged event to the monthPicker. Such as:

```
 var month = new List<int>() {1,3,5,7,8,10,12 };
           
            monthPicker.ValueChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if(month.Contains(monthPicker.Value))
                {
                    dayPicker.MaxValue = 31;
                }else if(monthPicker.Value == 2 && yearPicker.Value %4 == 0)
                {
                    dayPicker.MaxValue = 28;
                }else if(monthPicker.Value == 2 && yearPicker.Value % 4 != 0)
                {
                    dayPicker.MaxValue = 29;
                }
                else
                {
                    dayPicker.MaxValue = 30;
                }
            };
```

**Update**
What I mean is that you can set the default value with the `DateTime.Now`. And then set the maxvalue of the day picker.Such as:

```
yearPicker.Value = DateTime.Now.Year;
monthPicker.Value = DateTime.Now.Month;
dayPicker.MaxValue = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month);
dayPicker.Value = DateTime.Now.Day;// Set value must after set the min and max, or the default value will be 0
```

So it seems that we needn't to use `if() else`. We can just use the following code:

```
monthPicker.ValueChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    dayPicker.MaxValue = DateTime.DaysInMonth(yearPicker.Value,monthPicker.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  But I'm tried to create OnValueChanged event on monthPickerValueChange but event not create.  Please help how to create event inside OnCreateDialog. #Liyun Zhang

Comment: What does the `not create` mean?@Raj

Comment: Now it's work.Thank you so much @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Hii @Liyun Zhang - MSFT  What the value of day before month value change in dayPicker..?  If month is between 1 to 12 in monthPicker.

Comment: You can set it according to the current month.@Raj

Comment: Thank you. Can you please share me code. @Liyun

Comment: Wait a minute, what does the value of day mean? The current value or the maxvalue?@Raj

Comment: current day of month

Comment: If current month 5 then daypicker maxvalue 31. If current month 6 then  maxVal 30. same it on leap year. @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: You had set the value of the moth with the code `monthPicker.Value = cal.Get(CalendarField.Month) + 1`. So you can just recycle the judge code in the answer to set the maxvalue of the day.@Raj

Comment: Just I checked,  `dayPicker.MaxValue = cal.Get(CalendarField.DayOfMonth);`  So in dayPicker day is showing 0 to 19 . Zero value is also coming always. Please help  @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Please check the updated answer.@Raj

Comment: You can check the edited answer and use it to reduce the code.@Raj

Comment: Thank you! It's working, but 0 is also coming, Like 0 to 31  or 0 to 30 . @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: How to set current day of month in the dayPicker. @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Had you set the MinValue as 1?@Raj

Comment: Yes I have set Min val 1. @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Hii Now it's worked, I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much. @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Glad to help you, happy coding.@Raj

Comment: Hii @Liyun Zhang -MSFT _Have any suggestion how to fix this error._ **Can not resolve reference: Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources, referenced by Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources, or remove the reference to Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.**

Comment: When I'm trying to add nuGet package then this error is coming..  **Package Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources 1.4.2.1 is not compatible with monoandroid11.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0). Package Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources 1.4.2.1 supports:
  - monoandroid12.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0)
  - net6.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)**

Comment: Is it a xamarin.android project or a forms project?@Raj

Comment: You can post a new question and show more details.@Raj

Comment: Ya It's Xamarin.Android,   Sry Now I'm not able to post other question.

Comment: Why do you add the Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android package? It's always used in a forms project.@Raj

Comment: Actually, I am trying to convert Android Xamarin to AndroidX. 
@Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Had you checked the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx)?@Raj

Comment: It's shared project, some code i have written in Xamarin.Android.  I'm trying Migrate my Xamarin Android app with AndroidX. After Migrate this error is coming. @Liyun

Comment: Yes I follow same official document.

Comment: So this is in the android part of a forms project?@Raj

Comment: Yes android part @Liyun

Comment: If you want to use androidx, you need to remove the reference of the android support packages.@Raj

Comment: You can try to update the xamarin.forms version in your project.@Raj

Comment: ok, I am trying. thank you again @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: You can also add the Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources package with a low version, such as 1.3.0.@Raj

Comment: ok I'm trying @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: Low Version of Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources is working. Thank you so much @Liyun Zhang -MSFT

Comment: Please look this error. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72739051/xamarin-android-cannot-convert-from-androidx-fragment-app-fragmentmanager-to) @Liyun Zhang -MSFT

Comment: Which line cause the error?@Raj

Comment: _monthYearPickerDialog.Show(mFragManager, nameof(MonthYearPickerDialog));  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5844.png) here image of error.

Comment: What's the type of the `_monthYearPickerDialog`?@Raj

Comment: AlertDialog type

Comment: I got my mistake. Now I fixed this problem. Thank you. @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: All right, happy coding.@Raj