# Xamarin Android : cannot convert from 'AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager' to 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying Migrate my Xamarin Android app with AndroidX.
After Migrate this error is coming.

[cannot convert from 'AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager' to 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5844.png)

```
using AndroidX.Fragment.App;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;

 private void ShowDatePicker()
    {
        if (_monthYearPickerDialog == null)
        {
            _monthYearPickerDialog = new MonthYearPickerDialog();
            _monthYearPickerDialog.OnDateTimeChanged += OnDateTimeChanged;
            _monthYearPickerDialog.OnClosed += OnClosed;
        }
        _monthYearPickerDialog.Date = Element.Date;
        var appcompatActivity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity as AppCompatActivity;
        var mFragManager = appcompatActivity?.SupportFragmentManager;
        if (mFragManager != null)
        {
            _monthYearPickerDialog.Show(mFragManager, nameof(MonthYearPickerDialog));
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix types from Support.V4 namespace with AndroidX namespace. So it is super weird that you are defining this in the top of the file:

```
using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using SupportV4 = Android.Support.V4.App;
```

You should use Fragment from `AndroidX.Fragment` instead.

Stop mixing up things and your errors will go away.

Comment: Now changed mix namespace with `using AndroidX.Fragment.App;` but still same problem is coming. @Cheesebaron

Comment: Your `_monthYearPickerDialog` also needs to be updated to use AndroidX, otherwise you are going to have a bad time.

Comment: Updated `_monthYearPickerDialog` but still same. @Cheesebaron

Comment: From here on you need to provide more information. Hard to help with what you have given. But I am pointing out _ALL_ your classes that use old Support classes need to be switched over to use AndroidX stuff. Do yourself a favor and just uninstall all the Support packages and only have AndroidX, makes it more obvious what you need to change.

Comment: OK thank you, I am trying it now. @Cheesebaron

Comment: Hii @Cheesebaron, now this error is coming can you give some suggestion `Error: failed linking file resources. ZZAPP.Android`

Comment: Did you enable R8 or Proguard? What rules did you provide the linker?

Comment: R8 is enable and Linker is none. @Cheesebaron

Comment: This error is came after Migrate to AndroidX.